# C++ server/client networking

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, ldap

I'm working on a project that will include a server and a client component that will send/receive requests / information over TCP/IP. The server component will be developed in c++ and I will be using `boost.asio` libraries. Client component will be an excel add-in and will be developed in visual basic. I have few general questions and please note that I'm not expecting any specific response here but expecting to hear some concepts so I can focus on.

My questions are as below.

1. The server and the client will be developed in different languages, is there anything to worry about socket communication between two developing languages?
2. I want the application to have login/authentication mechanism through integration with LDAP systems. Is there any c++ libraries that I can use for this purpose? (like `boost.asio` for TCP)
3. Is there any concept that you can suggest user session management in c++
4. As part of my application, there will be need to transfer data from the server to the client or vice versa. This data can sometime be like hundreds to thousands rows with hundred of columns. What is the best way to transfer such data through sockets? Is arrays good for this?

I know my questions are very high level and basic but your answers will point me the right direction and will help me to focus on the right concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The server and the client will be developed in different languages, is there anything to worry about socket communication between two developing languages?

Not really, as long as you have a clearly defined wire format. Either use an existing one, like HTTP/JSON, or define it yourself explicitly. When the interface is a bit more complicated, consider to use something like `CORBA` or `ICE`.

> 2. I want the application to have login/authentication mechanism through integration with LDAP systems. Is there any c++ libraries that I can use for this purpose? (like boost.asio for TCP)

There is a C++ API for [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/). I have no experience with it, so no recommendation or warning here.

> 3. Is there any concept that you can suggest user session management in c++

It depends on what you need. The easiest approach is a vector of shared pointers to session objects ordered by age, but those sessions will all be invalid when the process ist restarted. Sessions in `memcached` survive a restart of the process. When you want to survive the restart of a machine, I'd prefer the session data in a relational database, or files.

> 4. As part of my application, there will be need to transfer data from the server to the client or vice versa. This data can sometime be like hundreds to thousands rows with hundred of columns. What is the best way to transfer such data through sockets? Is arrays good for this?

You might use a simple format for each object and simply stream the objects. E.g. CSV, or JSON. Also consider a binary fixed format, when most of your information is not already text. What is the best depends on the type of data, of course.